# Is the rtorrent tag useful? If so, should we retag these posts?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed a new tag [rtorrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rtorrent).

It only has one post, but I did my usual thing of running a [search which turned up ~40 questions mentioning rtorrent](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=rtorrent+is%3Aq).

Is this a tag we need? If so

- should old posts mentioning it be retagged?
- who can make a nice tag wiki for it? (not me, I am clueless)

Comment: Have added the tag to posts that seemed to benefit from it and also created [rutorrent] and am now working on that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have tags for some other BitTorrent programs<sup>**1**</sup>, such as [deluge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/deluge), [ktorrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ktorrent), [transmission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/transmission), [qbittorrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/qbittorrent),[utorrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/utorrent), and--though it's only on a handful of questions and I don't think I know anyone who uses it anymore--[vuze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vuze).

It looks like we also have a number of questions about those programs that don't have those tags. Assuming we do retag posts with [rtorrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rtorrent), we could add appropriate tags to some other BitTorrent-related posts as well.

I use qBittorrent and the [qbittorrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/qbittorrent) tag has helped me search for questions and answers. In [at least one case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256202/how-to-upgrade-qbittorrent-to-the-latest-stable-upstream-version), I believe that noticing the tag on a question led me to read the question and post an answer, though it's possible I'd have noticed and answered anyway. I presume the [rtorrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rtorrent) tag will confer a similar benefit. It's not as popular as several other BitTorrent programs but I *think* it does see significant use.

I'd say **yes**, we should add the [rtorrent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rtorrent) tag to posts it applies to, including old posts.

<sub>**1**: It's common to call them "[BitTorrent clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients)" but I use the more awkward-sounding term "BitTorrent program" because, from a networking standpoint, these programs behave both as a client and as a server. When BitTorrent was new, some people called them "servents" (server/clients) but that terminology doesn't seem to have caught on. (The other distinction for BitTorrent is between *client* and *tracker*, but many BitTorrent "clients" have the ability to operate as a traditional centralized tracker, and almost all of them support distributed tracking, usually via [DHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table), which is more significant today than centralized tracking.)</sub>

Comment: As to your footnote: I think "client" is fine here even though the Torrent protocol doesn’t fit into the client-server paradigm. However, it’s still a client application for a communication protocol and I’ve heard the term “client“ a bunch of in relation to “allows the use of [not-necessarily-client-server communication protocol]”.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I agree that "client" is fine, since it has become the generally accepted term and is usually clear, and I definitely wouldn't edit that term out of posts. I'm not really sure about your reasoning though--it's also a server application for a communication protocol.